# How to insert 'Quarterly Dates' using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to generate quarterly dates using for loop using an existing line of code for generating monthly dates.

```
list_of_months = []
for y in range(2023,2027):
    for m in range(12):
        if (y==2026) and (m>0):
            continue
        list_of_months.append(datetime.datetime(year=y, month=m+1, day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I tried to change the value of month from "month=m+1" to "month=m+3" and I'm getting the following error.

```
list_of_qaurters = []
for y in range(2023,2027):
    for m in range(12):
        if (y==2026) and (m>0):
            continue
        list_of_qaurters.append(datetime.datetime(year=y, month=m+1, day=1).strftime('%y-%m-%d'))
```

```
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Comment: if you change it to `month=m+3` then the possible month values derived from `range(12)` will range from 3..14, hence the ValueError

Comment: If you want quarterly dates I guess that would be Jan Apr, Jul, Oct? So for `datetime` that would be months 1, 4, 7, 10 ... you could change your loop to iterate over only those values `for m in (1, 4, 7, 10)` and then just `month=m`

Comment: ...and with the skip quarters for 2026 updated to `if (y==2026) and (m>1)`

Comment: It's working but it's printing year as '23' instead of '2023'. What could be the cause as for months it's printing year in yyyy format?

Comment: Replacing '%y' with '%Y' fixed it

Comment: Have a look at https://strftime.org/ ... `%y` prints a 2 digit year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize iterations for date increment, I suggest to use [dateuti](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)l module.

first you need to install it.

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

list_of_qaurters = []
start_year = year= 2023
next_qaurter_date =datetime.datetime(year=start_year, month=1, day=1)
end_qaurter_date = datetime.datetime(year=2027, month=12, day=31)
list_of_qaurters.append(next_qaurter_date.strftime('%y-%m-%d'))

while next_qaurter_date < end_qaurter_date:
    next_qaurter_date +=  relativedelta(months=+3)
    if (next_qaurter_date<=end_qaurter_date):
        list_of_qaurters.append(next_qaurter_date.strftime('%y-%m-%d'))
    

print(list_of_qaurters)
```